# Navigation tabs getting TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular4-router

I can’t navigate from one page to another.
Getting Error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   '_willLeave' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '_willLeave'
>   of undefined
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:58523:32 I have the array of pages:

```
 pages = [
    { pageName: 'ListPage', title: 'Before', icon: 'flame', id: 'before'},
    { pageName: 'Stage1Page', title: 'After', icon: 'help-circle', id: 'AfterTab'},
    { pageName: 'NewsPage', title: 'Profit', icon: 'body', id: 'ProfitTab'},
  ];
```

and the HTML:

```
 <super-tabs tabsPlacement="top" toolbarBackground="secondary" toolbarColor="light" indicatorColor="light"
  (tabSelect)="onTabSelect($event)">
  <super-tab *ngFor="let page of pages" [root]="page?.pageName" [icon]="page?.icon" [id]="page?.id"></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

**
    I see the tabs for a sec then I am getting the error. also when I am moving to the next tab.

I just need simple navigation. How should I do it?
Thanks!!

Comment: post more related code to help you better

Comment: Same issue here, did you fix it?